# How to set depth of simple JAVA web crawler

Tags: java, web-crawler, jsoup

I wrote a simple recursive web crawler to fetch just the URL links from the web page recursively.

Now I am trying to figure out a way to limit the crawler using depth but I am not sure how to limit the crawler by specific depth (I can limit the crawler by top N links but I want to limit using depth)

`For Ex: Depth 2 should fetch Parent links -> children(s) links--> children(s) link`

Any inputs is appreciated.

```
    public class SimpleCrawler {

    static Map<String, String> retMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();    

        public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
         StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();  
         Map<String, String> map = (returnURL("http://www.google.com"));
         recursiveCrawl(map);
          for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : retMap.entrySet()) {
            sb.append(entry.getKey());
          }
        }

        public static void recursiveCrawl(Map<String, String> map)
                throws IOException {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                Map<String, String> recurSive = returnURL(key);
                recursiveCrawl(recurSive);
            }
        }

        public synchronized static Map<String, String> returnURL(String URL)
                throws IOException {

            Map<String, String> tempMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Document doc = null;
            if (URL != null && !URL.equals("") && !retMap.containsKey(URL)) {
                System.out.println("Processing==>" + URL);
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(URL);
                    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "proxy");
                    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "port");
                    doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
                    if (doc != null) {
                        Elements links = doc.select("a");
                        String FinalString = "";
                        for (Element e : links) {
                            FinalString = "http:" + e.attr("href");
                            if (!retMap.containsKey(FinalString)) {
                                tempMap.put(FinalString, FinalString);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                retMap.put(URL, URL);
            } else {
                System.out.println("****Skipping URL****" + URL);
            }
            return tempMap;
        }

    }
```

EDIT1:

I thought of using worklist hence modified the code. I am not exactly sure how to set depth here too (I can set the number of webpages to crawl but not exactly depth). Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
public void startCrawl(String url) {
        while (this.pagesVisited.size() < 2) {
            String currentUrl;
            SpiderLeg leg = new SpiderLeg();
            if (this.pagesToVisit.isEmpty()) {
                currentUrl = url;
                this.pagesVisited.add(url);
            } else {
                currentUrl = this.nextUrl();
            }
            leg.crawl(currentUrl);
            System.out.println("pagesToVisit Size" + pagesToVisit.size());
            // SpiderLeg
            this.pagesToVisit.addAll(leg.getLinks());
        }
        System.out.println("\n**Done** Visited " + this.pagesVisited.size()
                + " web page(s)");
    }
```

Comment: You should avoid crawling recursive (depth first). Use a worklist (breadth first) that is updated after an url is visited (with the links to other pages). If you need a depth limit than you can limit the iterations over this worklist (or you keep the depth with the url and only update the worklist if the depth is < threshold).

Comment: Corona can you check my edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the non-recursive approach:

Keep a worklist of URLs `pagesToCrawl` of type `CrawlURL`

```
class CrawlURL {
  public String url;
  public int depth;

  public CrawlURL(String url, int depth) {
    this.url = url;
    this.depth = depth;
  }
}
```

initially (before entering the loop):

```
Queue<CrawlURL> pagesToCrawl = new LinkedList<>();
pagesToCrawl.add(new CrawlURL(rootUrl, 0)); //rootUrl is the url to start from
```

now the loop:

```
while (!pagesToCrawl.isEmpty()) { // will proceed at least once (for rootUrl)
  CrawlURL currentUrl = pagesToCrawl.remove();
  //analyze the url
  //updated with crawled links
}
```

and the updating with links:

```
if (currentUrl.depth < 2) {
  for (String url : leg.getLinks()) { // referring to your analysis result
    pagesToCrawl.add(new CrawlURL(url, currentUrl.depth + 1));
  }
}
```

You could enhance CrawlURL with other meta data (e.g. link name, referrer,. etc.).

**Alternative:**
In my upper comment I mentioned a generational approach. Its a bit more complex than this one. The basic Idea is to keep to lists (`currentPagesToCrawl` and `futurePagesToCrawl`) together with a generation variable (starting with 0 and increasing every time `currentPagesToCrawl` gets empty). All crawled urls are put into the `futurePagesToCrawl` queue and if `currentPagesToCrawl` both lists will be switched. This is done until the generation variable reaches 2.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a depth parameter on the signature of your recursive method eg

on your main

```
recursiveCrawl(map,0);
```

and

```
public static void recursiveCrawl(Map<String, String> map, int depth) throws IOException {
    if (depth++ < DESIRED_DEPTH) //assuming initial depth = 0
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            Map<String, String> recurSive = returnURL(key);
            recursiveCrawl(recurSive, depth);
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
static int maxLevels = 10;

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
     ...
     recursiveCrawl(map,0);
     ...
}

public static void recursiveCrawl(Map<String, String> map, int level) throws IOException {
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Map<String, String> recurSive = returnURL(key);
        if (level < maxLevels) {
            recursiveCrawl(recurSive, ++level);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you can use a `Set` instead of a `Map`.